# Concatenate cells based on a condition

Tags: google-sheets, concatenation, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I look for the following: I have columns with part names that make up a particular product, where I inform if the parts are defective or not. When the part is OK the default information is set to "#". All defects have a depreciation value from 0 to 10.

I want to concatenate in one cell all the defects that depreciate the product. In another cell, the defects that do not depreciate.
Here's the test sheet:

[image]

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HX2eko7v15mDja6_KlajmUaHkY4SCmKfELvPxqgnDUA/edit#gid=0

Actually I got a solution, however, there are 18 columns and the formula will be very large. Could someone come up with a smarter solution?
Here's my current script:

```
=IFERROR(CONCATENATE(LEFT(CONCATENATE(IF(A2<>"#";IF(VLOOKUP(A2;$H$2:$I$5;2;FALSE)<>0;A2&", ";"");"");IF(B2<>"#";IF(VLOOKUP(B2;$H$2:$I$5;2;FALSE)<>0;B2&", ";"");"");IF(C2<>"#";IF(VLOOKUP(C2;$H$2:$I$5;2;FALSE)<>0;C2&", ";"");"");IF(D2<>"#";IF(VLOOKUP(D2;$H$2:$I$5;2;FALSE)<>0;D2&", ";"");""));LEN(CONCATENATE(IF(A2<>"#";IF(VLOOKUP(A2;$H$2:$I$5;2;FALSE)<>0;A2&", ";"");"");IF(B2<>"#";IF(VLOOKUP(B2;$H$2:$I$5;2;FALSE)<>0;B2&", ";"");"");IF(C2<>"#";IF(VLOOKUP(C2;$H$2:$I$5;2;FALSE)<>0;C2&", ";"");"");IF(D2<>"#";IF(VLOOKUP(D2;$H$2:$I$5;2;FALSE)<>0;D2&", ";"");"")))-2);".");"OK")
```

and

```
=IFERROR(CONCATENATE(LEFT(CONCATENATE(IF(A2<>"#";IF(VLOOKUP(A2;$H$2:$I$5;2;FALSE)=0;A2&", ";"");"");IF(B2<>"#";IF(VLOOKUP(B2;$H$2:$I$5;2;FALSE)=0;B2&", ";"");"");IF(C2<>"#";IF(VLOOKUP(C2;$H$2:$I$5;2;FALSE)=0;C2&", ";"");"");IF(D2<>"#";IF(VLOOKUP(D2;$H$2:$I$5;2;FALSE)=0;D2&", ";"");""));LEN(CONCATENATE(IF(A2<>"#";IF(VLOOKUP(A2;$H$2:$I$5;2;FALSE)=0;A2&", ";"");"");IF(B2<>"#";IF(VLOOKUP(B2;$H$2:$I$5;2;FALSE)=0;B2&", ";"");"");IF(C2<>"#";IF(VLOOKUP(C2;$H$2:$I$5;2;FALSE)=0;C2&", ";"");"");IF(D2<>"#";IF(VLOOKUP(D2;$H$2:$I$5;2;FALSE)=0;D2&", ";"");"")))-2);".");"OK")
```

Answer (score 0):

paste in **D2**:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF((A2:D<>"")*(A2:D<>"#"); A2:D&","; ));;999^99))); ",$"; "."))
```

[image: 0]

---

paste in **E2**:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B2:B<>""; IF(B2:B="#"; "OK" ; B2:B)&"."; ))
```

[image: 0]

### [spreadsheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Rs3Fn284lQdoURzSLijAGN4wFChTq-EJxbacjysiKoY/edit#gid=0)

Comment: I guess I couldn't be clear ... I don't speak english and use google translator.
In a cell I need to concatenate the defects that monetarily depreciate the piece. In another cell I want to concatenate defects that do not depreciate.
In cell E3, "Piece2 Scratch" should not appear. But in cell F3, yes.

Comment: See the test sheet again, please. Defects in columns A: D are validated in columns H: I in this example. When the value in "I" = 0, I want it to concatenate in column F. Otherwise, in column E. "Defect 'X'" are random. I managed to solve it, but since there are 18 columns in all, I would just like to know if there is a simpler resolution.